# How to setup Komodo Edit for Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, komodoedit

I would like to use Komodo Edit to edit scripts written in Python 3.2. How do I setup Komodo Edit to run the Python 3.2 interpreter? I am using the latest version of Mac OSX.

The reason I ask because I am currently using Komodo Edit and am running some version of the Python interpreter. When I use the `print(b, end=' ')` command, I get and error pointing to `end=' '`. I think this is because Komodo is using Python 2.6.1 which is the default on the Mac.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The Komodo Built-in Help was not installed?

Comment: It is installed and I've gone through it already, however I am getting an error with the following statement `print(b, end=' ')`

Comment: And the configuration options are **not** in the built-in help?  Amazing that this one thing would be omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the default Python interpreter in `Preferences -> Languages -> Python`.

Comment: I've tried that but I still get an error when I run this `print(1, end=' ')`. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem
try to use python3.1 %F in Komodo's run command tool instead of 
%(python3) %F

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Thierry's answer got me on the right track.
When using the run command, instead of using **%(python) -u "%F"** I 
needed to add a 3 after python **%(python3) -u "%F"**

```
%(python) -u "%F" (run command)   
import sys  
print(sys.version_info)   
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

%(python3) -u "%F" (run command)    
import sys     
print(sys.version_info)    
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=1, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```